# Select the rows at the end of a dataframe which is frequently accumulating rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to cut out the last 14 rows of a dataframe and make them into their own dataframe. The problem is that every few days, we add more rows to the end, but we always want the last 14 rows.  The dataframe is ordered by dates, for example:

```
      Date    SW_30cm_b ST_30cm_b NO3_30ppm
 2015-06-22    85.729    19.548    17.864
 2015-06-23    83.844    18.736    17.514
 2015-06-24    82.619    17.984    17.297
 2015-06-25    80.439    17.815    16.859
 2015-06-26    77.227    17.756    16.132
 2015-06-27    74.436    17.720    15.468
```

A dplyr answer isn't necessary, but would be great!

Comment: Use `tail(dfname, 14)`

Comment: I wasn't clear, but I would also like them removed (gone) from the first dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already two convenient fuctions for that, `head` and `tail`:

```
last14 <- data %>% tail(14) # gets last 14 observations from data
data   <- data %>% head(-14) # excludes last 14 observations from data
```

Comment: Pipe overkill. `tail(data,14)` will do nicely, and save keystrokes, and lose nothing in readability.

Comment: (I would suggest you add `library(magrittr)` here as it is unlikely all readers will know what or where `%>%` comes from, nor what it means, especially the OP given the nature of their question.)

Comment: @DavidArenburg the OP is using dplyr this will probably fit in larger chain of his code

Comment: Gavin still has a good point regarding other readers. I'm generally a big fan of pipes, but for a single command like this they make code less clear and require more typing.

Answer (score 12):

Try

```
df <- head(df, -14)
```

Where the `-14` is the negative of the number of rows you want to drop from data frame `df`

As in

```
> nrow(mtcars)
[1] 32
> tail(mtcars, 2)
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
Maserati Bora 15.0   8  301 335 3.54 3.57 14.6  0  1    5    8
Volvo 142E    21.4   4  121 109 4.11 2.78 18.6  1  1    4    2
> mtcars2 <- head(mtcars, -2)
> nrow(mtcars2)
[1] 30
> mtcars2
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need dplyr for this but I included a version of that as well but the tail() function in Base R will work just fine.

Create sample data frame.

```
data<-data.frame(Factor1=rep(LETTERS[1:5],each=20),Factor2=sample(letters[1:10],100,replace=TRUE),Var1=rnorm(100,2,4),Var2=rpois(100,2))
```

You don't really need dplyr, the tail function in base R will take care of it.

```
last_rows <- tail(data, n = 14L)
```

If you're really dead-set on using dplyr, you could do something like this...

```
library(dplyr)

last_rows <- filter(tail(data, n = 14L))
```

The main advantage to dplyr would be to use the arrange() function to make sure your dates are lined up correctly (if necessary.)

```
#Where "Factor2" is your date
library(dplyr)

arrange(data, Factor2)
last_rows <- filter(tail(data, n = 14L))
```

Comment: Wrapping `tail()` in `filter()` does nothing. Filter does nothing unless you give it a second argument.